# Azure Ad terraform Config, where does the Client Id come from?

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform-provider-azure

I have the following terraform config.

```
# Terraform Block
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 3.0"
    }
  }
}

# Provider Block
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

```
# Datasources
# https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/data-sources/client_config

data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

output "object_id" {
  value = data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id
}

output "client_id" {
  value = data.azuread_client_config.current.client_id
}

output "tenant_id" {
  value = data.azuread_client_config.current.tenant_id
}
```

When I plan and then apply, I get the following output.

```
Outputs:

client_id = "04b07795-8ddb-YYYY-bbee-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
object_id = "3603657a-34b8-YYYY-b7df-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
tenant_id = "35b02984-c026-YYYY-8cb3-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

I could figure out where object_id and tenant_id come from. See below, I have screen shots to show.

But I could not figure out client_id source.

Here is where object_id and tenant_id come from.

1. First the object id.

[image: Active Directory Users]

[image: Active Directory Users 2]

[image: Active Directory Users Overview]

2. And now the tenant id.

[image: Azure Active Directory TenantId]

So the question again, what is this client id and where does this come from?

### Update

I dont see anything in the enterprise applications tab of the AD. What am I missing?

[image: Enterprise applications]

Answer (score 1):

I checked the clientId that resulted from the below output

```
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

output "object_id" {
  value = data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id
}

output "client_id" {
  value = data.azuread_client_config.current.client_id
}

output "tenant_id" {
  value = data.azuread_client_config.current.tenant_id
}
```

[image]

- If I check with that Id in azure Ad applications, it the `Microsoft Azure CLIs` **`applicationId`**

[image]

- This  client ID or (application ID) is the appId of the one which
  used to authenticate to ( i.e; the application used for delegated
  authentication.) or is linked to the authenticated principal.
- As in azure  to deploy Terraform configurations , we need to complete
  authentication.
- Terraform can actually  use the current account logged into Azure CLI
  for authentication which is my case.

**Reference:** [client_config#attributes-reference | registry.terraform.io](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/data-sources/client_config#attributes-reference)

Comment: I dont see anything under Enterprise apps, plz see my update.

Comment: have you searched that object id under app registrations,please check if you can find any in the same tenant that was in the output?

Comment: I'm in the same situation, trying to locate the client_Id, everything else I can find.  Did you managed to find it?